# How can I have Laravel mix only compile my Javascript?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Right now running "npm run dev" takes about 20 seconds. Is there a way to only have it compile my Javascript to run faster? Using Vue requires running this feature often. Thanks!

Comment: Need more info on this.  You're able to add whatever you like into Mix's Webpack-based asset compilation so what do you want to exclude and do you only want to exclude it in the development environment, etc.?

Comment: There will always be a delay in the startup time for `npm run dev`. I would suggest using `npm run watch` so that you don't have the initial overhead ever time you want to compile your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "only" compile javascript. The only thing (that might help you) you can do is running `npm run watch`, which only compiles changed files again.

Related: [How to run only one webpack process in Laravel Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886928/how-to-run-only-one-webpack-process-in-laravel-application/42889660#42889660)