# How to run only one webpack process in Laravel Application?

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.4

is there any utility to pass through npm run dev variable that may compile only one process

for example

npm run dev --sass or npm run dev --js --styles --scripts

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such function available by default. The only thing (that might help you) you can do is running `npm run watch`, which only compiles changed files again.